# React useState not updating state when using callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I click the button to run `rollDice()` it is not updating `state`.
I can not figure out why, because it is updating correctly on my console logs. But the `state` is not
refreshing.

```
import React from "react"
import Die from "./Die"

export default function App() {

let diceObj = allNewDice()
    diceObj = diceObj.map((dice) => ({value: dice, isHeld: false}))
    
const [dice, setDice] = React.useState(diceObj)
console.log("refreshed")

function allNewDice() {
    const newDice = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newDice.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6))
    }
    return newDice
}



function rollDice() {
    setDice(prevState => {
        for (let i = 0; i < prevState.length; i++){
            prevState[i].value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6)
        }
        console.log(prevState)
        return prevState
    })
    console.log(dice)
}

const diceElements = dice.map(die => <Die value={die.value} />)

return (
    <main>
        <div className="dice-container">
            {diceElements}
        </div>
        <button className="roll-dice" onClick={rollDice}>Roll</button>
    </main>
)
}
```

I got it working another way but its bothering me because this seems like it should work too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you are not updating!**

you cannot update the value of `prevState` so when you are returning `prevState` after your changes your are actually returning the same `prevState` therefore the component does not render because it only does when the prev value is different from the new, which is not the case

**one solution** is to create a copy of `prevState` you update it then you return it :

```
function rollDice() {
setDice(prevState => {
    var newValue = [...prevState];
    for (let i = 0; i < prevState.length; i++){
        newValue[i].value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6)
    }
    return newValue 
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i < prevState.length; i++){
  prevState[i].value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6)
}
```

This code is mutating the previous state, but react expects state to be immutable. So after you return `prevState`, react compares the old and new states, sees that they are the same array, and thus skips rendering because it thinks nothing has changed.

The fix is to create a new array and return that. For example:

```
setDice(prevState => {
  const nextState = prevState.map(die => {
    return {
      ...die,
      value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6)
    }
  });
  return nextState;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can clean up your code:

```
function rollDice() {
for(let i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
    const newValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    setDice(prevState => [
        ...prevState.slice(0, i),
        {
          value: newValue,
          isHeld: false,
        }
    ])    
}
```

Also I noted you could just create an object in the allNewDice() function and you wouldn't need to do the map up at the top.